# classCastexception when comparing two strings

Tags: java, string, compare, classcastexception

I found here on Stackoverflow what a "ClassCastException" is, but i don't see how to solve the problem in my case:

I have a class "Gebruiker" (=dutch for user). Each Gebruiker/User-object has a "String Gebruikersnaam (=username)" and a "String Password". The "Boolean type" decides if the user is an administrator (true) or a normal user (=false).

```
public class Gebruiker implements Serializable{

        private String gebruikersnaam;
        private String wachtwoord;
        private Boolean type;  //0 = user 1=super user

        public Gebruiker(String gebruikersnaam, String wachtwoord, Boolean type) {
            gebruikersnaam = this.gebruikersnaam;
            wachtwoord = this.wachtwoord;
            type = this.type;

        }
```

A method in this class returns the username as a String.

```
        /**
         * @return the gebruikersnaam
         */
        public String getGebruikersnaam() {
            return gebruikersnaam;
        }
```

In have an `ArrayList<Gebuiker> gebruikers;`, where i store all the Users.

The If-statement in the code below compares the username from a given "Gebruiker"-object using my methode `"gebr.getGebruikersnaam()"` with the text in a Username input field "LogOnName". So i compare a string with a string, but i get an error there...

```
 for (Gebruiker gebr : gebruikers) {
   //line 72 in the code: 
   if (gebr.getGebruikersnaam().equals(logOnName.getText())){
      //do something here

      }
    }
```

Part of the Stacktrace generated due to the error i can't solve:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to my.venster.Gebruiker
    at my.venster.zeeOnline.logOnGebruiker(zeeOnline.java:72)
    at my.venster.zeeOnline.logOnButtonActionPerformed(zeeOnline.java:910)
    at my.venster.zeeOnline.access$300(zeeOnline.java:30)
    at my.venster.zeeOnline$4.actionPerformed(zeeOnline.java:429)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
```

I understand that I may get a ClassCastException when I try to cast one type to another type that's incompatible with that type. ie an integer into a string, but here, I need a string from the User object, which is also a String.

Why do i get that annoying ClassCastException, when I try to do the login procedure for one user?

Comment: can you put the ccompelte code here i.e. zeeOnline.ajava line 72.Also,in your constructor assignment of local variable from instance variable is taking place ,it should be vice-versa.
this.gebruikersnaam = gebruikersnaam;

Comment: Pretty clear: `java.lang.String cannot be cast to my.venster.Gebruiker` on line 72.  Despite the supposed "safety" of generics, your ArrayList contains Strings.  (And all your assignments in the constructor are backwards.)

Answer (score 0):

Print `logOnName.getText()` and see if it prints a String or an Object. You have to do the assignment like this :

```
this.gebruikersnaam = gebruikersnaam;
this.wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
this.type = type;
```